# How to combine a list of timeDate into a single timeDate?

Tags: r, finance

I can generate a list of `timeDate` objects for New York Exchange. However, most of the analytical functions expect a single `timeDate` object. The underlying data representation is `POSIXct`, so I can't just append them like a vector or a list.

How to do it?

```
library(timeDate)
x <- lapply(c(1885: 1886), holidayNYSE)
x

[[1]]
NewYork
[1] [1885-01-01] [1885-02-23] [1885-04-03] [1885-11-03] [1885-11-26] [1885-12-25]

[[2]]
NewYork
[1] [1886-01-01] [1886-02-22] [1886-04-23] [1886-05-31] [1886-07-05] [1886-11-02] [1886-11-25]

class(x[[1]])
[1] "timeDate"
attr(,"package")
[1] "timeDate"

class(x[[1]]@Data)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

# ??? How to my two datetime objects ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `do.call` with `c`

```
x1 <- do.call(c, x)
x1
#NewYork
#[1] [1885-01-01] [1885-02-23] [1885-04-03] [1885-11-03] [1885-11-26] [1885-12-25] [1886-01-01] [1886-02-22] [1886-04-23] [1886-05-31] [1886-07-05] [1886-11-02]
#[13] [1886-11-25]

str(x1)
#Formal class 'timeDate' [package "timeDate"] with 3 slots
#  ..@ Data     : POSIXct[1:13], format: "1885-01-01 05:00:00" "1885-02-23 05:00:00" "1885-04-03 05:00:00" "1885-11-03 05:00:00" ...
#  ..@ format   : chr "%Y-%m-%d"
#  ..@ FinCenter: chr "NewYork"
```

and the structure of OP's `list` is

```
str(x)
#List of 2
#$ :Formal class 'timeDate' [package "timeDate"] with 3 slots
#  .. ..@ Data     : POSIXct[1:6], format: "1885-01-01 05:00:00" "1885-02-23 05:00:00" "1885-04-03 05:00:00" "1885-11-03 05:00:00" ...
#  .. ..@ format   : chr "%Y-%m-%d"
#  .. ..@ FinCenter: chr "NewYork"
# $ :Formal class 'timeDate' [package "timeDate"] with 3 slots
#   .. ..@ Data     : POSIXct[1:7], format: "1886-01-01 05:00:00" "1886-02-22 05:00:00" "1886-04-23 05:00:00" "1886-05-31 05:00:00" ...
#  .. ..@ format   : chr "%Y-%m-%d"
#  .. ..@ FinCenter: chr "NewYork"
```

Comment: I actually have 100+ objects in my list. Does `do.call` work with that number of objects?

Comment: @StudentT  It should work if all of them have the same structure.  The manual way is `c(x[[1]], x[[2]])` which we are avoiding here